# Rescaling of a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's suppose we have a hamiltonian that contains a term $\partial_x$ is there some rescaling of the wave function $\psi$ possible so that this term vanishes? I mean something like this $f \psi =  \tilde{\psi}$ with

$$\partial_x \left(\frac{1}{f}\tilde{\psi}\right)= A(x) \tilde{\psi} $$

where $A(x)$ does not contain any derivative operators.

Comment: What is $f$? Is it a number, or a function, or a functional?

Comment: a function of x

Comment: Is $f$ allowed to depend on $\psi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lone derivative by itself, then no, this isn't possible.

On the other hand, if you also have a second derivative in your operator (which happens in the overwhelming majority of cases where you'd want to do this), then yes, this is possible: if you consider, say, the reasonably-general combination
$$
\left[\frac12\partial_x^2 - i\alpha \partial_x\right] \psi(x),
$$
then you can define $\psi(x) = e^{i\kappa x}\tilde \psi(x)$ so that
\begin{align}
\left[\frac12\partial_x^2 - i\alpha \partial_x\right] \psi(x)
& =
\left[\frac12\partial_x^2 - i\alpha \partial_x\right] e^{i\kappa x}\tilde \psi(x)
\\ & =
\frac12 \left(
  e^{i\kappa x}\partial_x^2\tilde \psi(x)
  + 2 i\kappa e^{i\kappa x} \partial_x \tilde \psi(x)
  -  \kappa^2 e^{i\kappa x}\tilde \psi(x)
\right)
\\ & \qquad
-i\alpha \left(
  e^{i\kappa x}\partial_x\tilde \psi(x)
  + i\kappa e^{i\kappa x} \tilde \psi(x)
\right)
\\ & =
e^{i\kappa x}\left[
  \frac12\partial_x^2 
  + i(\kappa-\alpha) \partial_x
  - \frac12 \kappa^2 + \kappa \alpha
\right] \tilde \psi(x)
,
\end{align}
and you can make the $\partial_x$ term vanish by setting $\kappa=\alpha$. Once you do that, you're left with
\begin{align}
\left[\frac12\partial_x^2 - i\alpha \partial_x\right] \psi(x)
& =
e^{i\alpha x}\left[
  \frac12\partial_x^2 
  + \frac12 \alpha^2
\right] \tilde \psi(x)
,
\end{align}
with no first-order terms.